# C# Delegates in .NET 4.6 no longer compile to static

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, static, delegates

I have found switching over to .NET 4.6 (from .Net 4.5.2) that delegates declared with lambda expressions that previously evaluated to static no longer are.  Prior to switching over to VS 2015 and .NET 4.6, the following line of could would have evaluated actionMethod.Method.IsStatic to true.

```
Action<Dispatcher, EventHandler> actionMethod = (d, eh) => d.ShutdownStarted += eh;
```

With .NET 4.6, actionMethod.Method.IsStatic only ever evaluates to false.  Does anyone out there understand why this is?

Comment: A Roslyn change in VS2015.  Implementation detail of course.